# Is there a way to edit an auto generated file in Android on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-fragments

I am using `eclipse 4.4 (Luna)` and am trying to create my own fragment:

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                  container, false);
          return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have an error on `R.layout.fragment_display_message,` Which is as follows:

```
fragment_display message cannot be resolved or is not a field.
2 quick fixes available:
 - Create field fragment_display_message in type 'layout'
 - Create constant fragment_display_message in type 'layout'
```

When clicking either of these, creating the `field/constant` in the `XML` file I get the following error:

```
[2014-08-12 10:56:26 - MyFirstApp] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can fix this?

Comment: You cannot change R.java, btw, why do you want to edit `R` ? From your error, seems you have not created `fragment_display_message` in layout or you have error in any of your `*.xml`

Comment: @VenomVendor because of the error saying that fragment_display_message can not be resolved, and Eclipse tells me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities

- You are imporing `android.R`
- You have errors in your project, which is preventing `R` to be generated properly